# What is the best way to create Spark DataFrames using Spark Testing Base library?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing unit tests for one Spark method which takes multiple data frames as an input parameters and returns one data frame. Code for spark method looks like below:

```
class processor {
    def process(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
      // process and return resulting data frame
    }
}
```

Existing code for corresponding unit test is as follows:

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class TestProcess extends FlatSpec with DataFrameSuiteBase with Matchers {

  val p:Processor = new Processor

  "process()" should "return only one row" in {
    df1RDD = sc.parallelize(
      Seq("a", 12, 98999),
      Seq("b", 42, 99)
    )
   df1DF = spark.createDataFrame(df1RDD).toDF()

    df2RDD = sc.parallelize(
      Seq("X", 12, "foo", "spark"),
      Seq("Z", 42, "bar", "storm")
    )
   df2DF = spark.createDataFrame(df2RDD).toDF()

  val result = p.process(df1, df2)
  }

  it should "return spark row" in {
    df1RDD = sc.parallelize(
      Seq("a", 12, 98999),
      Seq("b", 42, 99)
    )
   df1DF = spark.createDataFrame(df1RDD).toDF()

    df2RDD = sc.parallelize(
      Seq("X", 12, "foo", "spark"),
      Seq("Z", 42, "bar", "storm")
    )
   df2DF = spark.createDataFrame(df2RDD).toDF()

  val result = p.process(df1, df2)
  }
}
```

This code works fine but it has problem that code to create RDD and DF is repeating in each test method. When I try to create RDD outside test methods or inside BeforeAndAfterAll() method, I get error about `sc` not available. It seems like `Spark Testing Base` library initiates `sc` and `spark` variables only inside test methods.

I would like to know if there is any way I can avoid writing this duplicate code?

---

Updated code after using `WordSpec` instead of using `FlatSpec`

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class TestProcess extends WordSpec with DataFrameSuiteBase with Matchers {

  val p:Processor = new Processor

  "process()" should {
    df1RDD = sc.parallelize(
        Seq("a", 12, 98999),
        Seq("b", 42, 99)
      )
    df1DF = spark.createDataFrame(df1RDD).toDF()

    df2RDD = sc.parallelize(
        Seq("X", 12, "foo", "spark"),
        Seq("Z", 42, "bar", "storm")
    )
    df2DF = spark.createDataFrame(df2RDD).toDF()
    val result = p.process(df1, df2)

    "return only one row" in {             
      result.count should equal(1)
    }

    "return spark row" in {
      // assertions to check if 'row' containing 'spark' in last column is in the result or not
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WordSpec` instead of `FlatSpec`, as it allows common initialization to be grouped before the test clauses, as in

```
"process()" should {
     df1RDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", 12, 98999),Seq("b", 42, 99))
     df1DF = spark.createDataFrame(df1RDD).toDF()
     df2RDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("X", 12, "foo", "spark"), Seq("Z", 42, "bar", "storm"))
     df2DF = spark.createDataFrame(df2RDD).toDF()
     "return only one row" in {
         ....
     }
     "return spark row" in {
         ....
     }
}
```

EDIT: Also, the following two lines of code hardly justify using a library (spark-testing-base):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").getOrCreate
val sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Add these to the top of your class, and you're all set with the SparkContext and all, and no NPEs.

EDIT: I just confirmed with my own test that the spark-testing-base **does not** work well with WordSpec. If you still want to use it, consider opening a bug report with the library author, as this is definitely an issue with the spark-testing-base.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer. I tried your solution but getting NPE like this 

[info] com.my.package.TestProcessor *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown inside "process()" should, construction cannot continue: null (TestProcessor.scala:50)

Comment: This NPE is at "process()" should { line

Comment: Post your updated code into the original post (include imports, they're often important in Scala). Is your `process()` method actually capable of being called several times? Does it, maybe, close some resources inside it?

Comment: Thanks for quick help. I have updated question with new code and `process()` method doesn't really close any resources. It just uses data frames passed to it as parameter , filters out some rows using business rules and spits back resulting data frame.

Comment: What are the Spark/ScalaTest/ScalaMock versions you use? I see a number of issues with your code, not sure if any of them are due to the version difference. 1. `sc.parallelize()` accepts only one Seq as parameter 2. `spark.createDataFrame()` needs the beanClass parameter in addition to the RDD 3. `p.process()` refers to `df1` and `df2`, neither of which is defined anywhere 4. all RDD and DF need to be defined as `val`s

Comment: Added a comment about your usage of spark-testing-base. You're essentially pulling in a library to save you two lines of code, not a good trade IMO

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I was thinking of skipping this library and you just confirmed on it. :)